# mean and variance of reciprocal normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, inverse

If $X$ is a normal distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. What would be the mean and variance of $Y = \dfrac{1}{X}$

Comment: What makes you think that the mean and/or variance exist? Both are defined by improper integrals; are you sure these integrals actually converge? Have you tried it explicitly with mean $0$ and variance $1$?

Comment: I didnot do that mathematically. However, I ran this code in the MATLAB:
a = randn(1000000,1);
b = 1./a;

The mean and variance of b does have some value. So I was interested in if there is a closed mathematical term, anyone has ever worked out.

Comment: Please accept answers to your other questions by pressing tick button. Many people do not like helping people who do not accept answers.

Comment: Which question, specifically?

Comment: Sorry didnt realise tey got no answers except self answers.

Comment: In your MATLAB code, try the experiment for different (but large enough) sample size and see if the sample mean and variance are consistent for different sample sizes. 
Matlab basically gives you an average value for the sample size, but it doesn't imply that mean exist.

Comment: see also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41896/varx-is-known-how-to-calculate-var1-x

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mean and variance do not exist. For the mean to exist, the integral

$\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\frac{1}{|x|} \text{d}x$

needs to be finite. This is clearly not the case.

Note it is necessary that mean exists for variance to exist.

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution

Note inverse gaussian is something completely different. It is connected to brownian motion hitting a level. I changed the title. The thing you are referring to is a reciprocal normal.

Comment: The integral is not finite since, denoting by $p(x)$ the density of a standard normal, $$\begin{array}{rl}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|} p(x)dx &=& 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} p(x)dx \\ & = & 2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} p(x) dx + 2\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}p(x)dx \\ & \ge & 2 p(1)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx + 2 \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}p(x)dx = \infty\end{array}$$ since $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$ is divergent and $p(x)$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$, so bounded below by $p(1)$.  (I assume the answerer knows this, I am writing it for future reference of anyone else slow like me.)

Comment: Why do we need the absolute sign here $\dfrac{1}{|x|}$?

Comment: Check the link in the post for criteria for mean to exist.