# Central Limit Theorem for transformed random variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces

The Central limit theorem (CTL) is often given similar to the entry in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) as:

> Suppose ${X_1, X_2, ...}$ is a sequence of independent and identically
>   distributed random variables with $E[X_i] = µ$ and $Var[X_i] = σ^2 < ∞$. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables
>   $\sqrt{n}(S_n − µ)$ convergence in distribution to a normal
>   distribution $N(0, σ^2)$

What happens if the the random variables are transformed by a function $g: X_i \mapsto Z_i$? Under what conditions does the CTL hold for the random variables $Z_i$?

I am especially interested in the cases where the $Z_i$ are elements of a Hilbert space of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lindeberg-Feller CLT](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/lectures/p93to100.pdf) would hold as long as the transformed sequence satisfies the [Lindeberg Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition)

Here is an example where the transformation does not allow CLT to hold:

$X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1), \;\;g:x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ , as the transformed sequence lacks a mean or variance. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution).