# Expected Value of Sample Variance

Tags: probability

If I have an estimator such as the sample variance
$$\hat{\sigma}^2_{} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}(x_k-\hat{x})^2$$

How do I calculate the expected value of the estimator if it passes through a non-linear transformation?
$$E(\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+\hat{\sigma}^2_{}}) $$

Comment: Jessica, do you have an answer to your question and could you update it? I have a similar question like you without knowing the information of distribution. thx

Answer (score 0):

So this is a tough one without knowing the distribution of the $(x_k)$ or whether the $x_k$ are i.i.d or not.

Assuming they are i.i.d. and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ has some distribution $K$, then its [not necessarily guaranteed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution) that $\mathbb{E}\big[\tfrac{1}{1+\hat{\sigma}^2}\big]$ is even defined without a little more info  on $K$.

Now, if we assume that $x_k$ are i.i.d Normal random variables with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$, then each $x_k^2$ will follow a Chi-squared distribution. The random variable $$\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k-1}^{N}X^2}$$ will follow whats called a [scaled-inverse Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_inverse_chi-squared_distribution).

$\mathbb{E}\big[\sum\limits_{k-1}^{N}X^2\big]^{-1} = \frac{N \sigma^{-2}}{N-2}$

Now this isn't exactly what you've asked for, but it might be a good first step.

Comment: Thanks measure. Apparently you can use slutskys theorem and show the sample variance converges to the variance asymptotically. Assuming you have finite mean/variance.