# Frequency pdf distribuiton

Tags: normal-distribution

The oscillatory frequency is defined by $F=1/T$. Given that T has a normal distribution $N(µ_t,\sigma_t$) how do I calculate the frequency distribution based on period $µ_t,\sigma_t$ ?

I assume that $\sigma_f = 1/\sigma_t$ does is not true, and this should be evaluated by using the delta method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution you are asking for is the reciprocal normal distribution, which is emphatically not another normal distribution, and in fact has no defined mean or variance.  See [mean and variance of reciprocal normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution) which asks basically the same question.

The question you may *mean* to be asking is that if in the position domain the distribution is $N(µ_t,\sigma_t$) what is the frequency decomposition.  This is a matter of doing a Fourier transform.  Here the mean is and sigma are defined.

That is, the distribution you may be looking for is
$$
\tilde{f}(k) = \int \frac{1}{\sigma_t\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{(t-\mu_t)^2}{2\sigma_t}}  e^{-2\pi ikt} dt
$$
with some factor of $2\pi$ to some power thrown in, depending on definitions.