# Conditional convergence of $\Bbb E[X^{-1}]$ for $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ as $\operatorname{pr}(X>0)\to 1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, means, cauchy-principal-value

This question references the post [Reciprocal of a normal variable with non-zero mean and small variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889153/reciprocal-of-a-normal-variable-with-non-zero-mean-and-small-variance/1889208#1889208)

In the question the OP simulated observations from an inverse normal distribution, i.e. distribution of $X^{-1}$ where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ were chosen such that $\operatorname{pr}(X>0)\approx1$.  He noted that under these conditions the sample of inverse-normal pseudo random numbers he generated seem to be well behaved in the sense that he was able to compute a sample mean and variance that yielded reasonable values. That said, if $\mu$ is allowed to get small (or $\sigma$ is allowed to get large) such that $\operatorname{pr}(X>0)$ departs from $1$, the sample statistics become more and more ill behaved.

In the answer by to this post it was stated that this behavior was an example of [conditional convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence).  After checking out the wiki page on conditional convergence I am still unsure how this behavior is an example of it.  I am looking for someone to (elaborate on)/(convince me) why mathematically this behavior is an example of conditional convergence. References supporting the answer would be nice too.