# Exponential of reciprocal normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

I am working with some probability distributions and I am wondering if the probability density function of the following distribution can be obtained. Consider a normal random variable $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then which would be the distribution of $Y=e^{-\frac{k}{X}}$.

My attempt:

- First rewrite the variable as $Y=e^{\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{k}X}}$.
- The quotient $Z=-\frac{1}{k}X$ will follow a normal distribution too, $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(-\frac{1}{k}\mu,\frac{1}{k^2}\sigma^2)$.
- The inverse of $Z$, $W=\frac{1}{Z}$ will follow a reciprocal normal distribution, we will call it $\mathcal{RN}(-\frac{1}{k}\mu,\frac{1}{k^2}\sigma^2)$ (The mean and variance refer to the original normal distribution, as the moments of the reciprocal are not defined). The pdf of such can be seen in [Do the moments of the reciprocal normal distribution exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3587820/do-the-moments-of-the-reciprocal-normal-distribution-exist) .
- Here is the point where I am stucked. It is a known fact that $e^X$ follows log-normal distribution. However, I do not know if such result can be related to the reciprocal normal distribution, or if it can be related to another one.

I would also be interested in the same problem but starting with a positive truncated normal variable, that is a random variable that only considers positive values. The $1/X$ of such is called reciprocal truncated normal distribution. I have been able to derive the probability density till the same point as before and get stucked on the exponential part. Info about this truncated distributions can be found in [On the convergence of time interval moments: caveat sciscitator](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0165027012000325?token=E4FEFD66186AF93305CB27772AE86C75230DF103880708007501D19E24F15EDCD225CC28FF6417DDE1013E0A834B0DCB).

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be a common distribution, though you can state the density and cumulative distribution function.  For example the density for $y>0$ and $k>0$ is $$\frac{k}{y \log(y)^2\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma }\exp\left(-\frac1{2\sigma^2} \left(\frac{-k}{\log(y)}-\mu\right)^2\right)$$

For example with $\mu=\sigma=k=2$ you get something looking like this (with about $9\%$ distribution above $8$ - hence the infinite mean)

[image: density]

Comment: How do you get such pdf? Does it have a name?

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez It is the usual change of variables approach applied to a normal density.  I would be surprised if it had a name, though you could try to invent one such as *log-reciprocal-normal*

Comment: How can this be a pdf if its area is not 1?

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez What makes you say its area is not $1$? I may have made a small error such as a constant, but simulation suggests the shape is reasonable

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. Thanks!