Expectation of Inverse-chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom
I need to find the expectation of $1/z^{2}$ where
$z \sim \operatorname{N}\left(0, 1\right)$:

I understand that $z^{2}$ is sampled according to the chi-distribution with $v = 1$ and so $1/z^{2}$ is sampled according to the Inverse-chi-squared distribution with $v = 1$.
But, the Wikipedia Page only mentions the expectation where $v > 2$, why is that ?, is it not defined when $v = 1$ ?.


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution
